# MySQL error 1064 on event

Tags: mysql, sql, events, triggers

This is the query that I want to execute on the event but it returns null and it does not insert any row to the table weekly.

```
insert into weekly (winddir,windspeedmph,windgustmph,windgustdir,windspdmph_avg2m,winddir_avg2m,windgustmph_10m,windgustdir_10m,humidity,tempf,rainin,dailyrainin,pressure,batt_lvl,light_lvl)
VALUE (
(select AVG(winddir) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(windspeedmph) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(windgustmph) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(windgustdir) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(windspdmph_avg2m) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(winddir_avg2m) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(windgustmph_10m) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(windgustdir_10m) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(humidity) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(tempf) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(rainin) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(dailyrainin) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(pressure) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(batt_lvl) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()),
(select AVG(light_lvl) from daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW())
)
```

And when I try this way:

```
insert into weekly (winddir,windspeedmph,windgustmph,windgustdir,windspdmph_avg2m,winddir_avg2m,windgustmph_10m,windgustdir_10m,humidity,tempf,rainin,dailyrainin,pressure,batt_lvl,light_lvl)
VALUE (
(select AVG(winddir) from daily ),
(select AVG(windspeedmph) from daily ),
(select AVG(windgustmph) from daily ),
(select AVG(windgustdir) from daily ),
(select AVG(windspdmph_avg2m) from daily ),
(select AVG(winddir_avg2m) from daily ),
(select AVG(windgustmph_10m) from daily ),
(select AVG(windgustdir_10m) from daily ),
(select AVG(humidity) from daily ),
(select AVG(tempf) from daily ),
(select AVG(rainin) from daily ),
(select AVG(dailyrainin) from daily ),
(select AVG(pressure) from daily ),
(select AVG(batt_lvl) from daily ),
(select AVG(light_lvl) from daily )
)
SELECT * FROM daily WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
```

I get the error 1064.

can someone help me pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can greatly simplify your query by using `insert into . . .` with a single aggregation query:

```
Insert into weekly (winddir, windspeedmph, windgustmph, windgustdir, windspdmph_avg2m,
                    winddir_avg2m, windgustmph_10m, windgustdir_10m, humidity,
                    tempf, rainin, dailyrainin, pressure, batt_lvl, light_lvl)
    select AVG(winddir), AVG(windspeedmph), AVG(windgustmph), AVG(windgustdir), AVG(windspdmph_avg2m),
           AVG(winddir_avg2m), AVG(windgustmph_10m), AVG(windgustdir_10m), AVG(humidity),
           AVG(tempf), AVG(rainin), AVG(dailyrainin), AVG(pressure), AVG(batt_lvl), AVG(light_lvl) 
    from daily
    where `timeStamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and NOW()
```

My guess is that you have no data in the past day.  Perhaps you should change the `1 Day` to `7 Day` (based on the name of your table).